# ANT build error with NullPointerException

Tags: java, xml, build, ant

I use Ant to build my application. Previously the same build.xml was getting successfully build but currently I am facing a null pointer exception and I am not sure about the reason why. Please find the details of the environment I am using and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
Server  : Weblogic 12cR2 12.2.1.3
Java    : 1.8
Eclipse : Oxygen
Ant Version : Default provided with Eclipse Oxygen (1.10.1)
```

Code Snippet :

```
build.xml
------------
<target name="build"  description="Compile and build the application archive">   
    <delete dir="${work.dir}"/>
    <antcall target="make.ear" />
</target>


<ant antfile="${basedir}/build_archive.xml" 
    target="prepare.webservice.jar" inheritall="true" inheritrefs="true">
    <property name="app_name" value="sp_docman_ws"/>
    <property name="src.dir" 
    value="${basedir}/../SPDocumentManagementEjb/src"/>
</ant>

-------------------------
build_target.xml
-------------------------

<target name="prepare.webservice.jar" depends="clean.work.dir">
        <taskdef name="jwsc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask" classpathref="common.classpath"/>
        <!-- For JAR -->
        <jwsc srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${dist.dir}" keepGenerated="yes" compiler="modern" verbose="false" srcEncoding="UTF-8">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="app.classpath" />
                <fileset dir="${dist.dir}" includes="sp_common.jar,sp_docman_ejb.jar" />
            </classpath>
            <jws file="com/docman/webservice/SPDocManWebService.java" generateWsdl="true" name="${app_name}" type="JAXWS" />
        </jwsc>
</target>
```

I am getting error on the below line :

```
<jwsc srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${dist.dir}" keepGenerated="yes" compiler="modern" verbose="false" srcEncoding="UTF-8">
```

Error :

```
build_target.xml:80: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:575)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:142)
```

Providing the complete stacktrace :

```
Complete Stack Trace :


prepare.webservice.jar:
     [jwsc] warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
     [jwsc] Verbose is on.
     [jwsc] JWS: processing module sp_docman_ws
     [jwsc] Parsing source files
     [jwsc] Parsing source files
[AntUtil.deleteDir] Deleting directory C:\Users\Som\AppData\Local\Temp\_tfcc6v
[AntUtil.deleteDir] Deleting directory C:\Users\Som\AppData\Local\Temp\_tfcc6v
      [ant] Exiting C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build_target.xml.
  [antcall] Exiting C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build.xml.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build.xml:395: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build.xml:328: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build_target.xml:80: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:575)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:142)
Caused by: C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build.xml:328: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build_target.xml:80: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:575)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:34)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: C:\Somnath\codebase\SPBuild\build_target.xml:80: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:249)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:34)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.javadoc.JavadocClassBuilder.getImports(JavadocClassBuilder.java:179)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.javadoc.JavadocClassBuilder.build(JavadocClassBuilder.java:140)
    at com.bea.util.jam.provider.CompositeJamClassBuilder.build(CompositeJamClassBuilder.java:51)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.JamClassLoaderImpl.loadClass(JamClassLoaderImpl.java:128)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.JamServiceImpl.getAllClasses(JamServiceImpl.java:65)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.JamUtil.parseSource(JamUtil.java:168)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.JamUtil.parseSource(JamUtil.java:136)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsLoader.loadJClasses(JwsLoader.java:187)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsLoader.load(JwsLoader.java:75)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.loadWebServices(JwsModule.java:631)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.generate(JwsModule.java:432)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.build(JwsModule.java:306)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:242)
    ... 42 more

Total time: 3 minutes 50 seconds
```

Please help me out !!! Thank You !

Comment: Please share the complete stack trace

Comment: Complete Stack Trace added in the question